# Number of characteristic subgroups of an abelian group of order p^4?

Tags: group-theory

Is it possible to determine the number of characteristic subgroups of an abelian group of order $p^4$? (We can ignore the case $p=2 $).

I believe the group $Z_p \times Z_p \times Z_p \times Z_p $ has no proper nontrivial characteristic subgroups.

For $Z_p \times Z_{p^3} $, I believe there are two characteristic subgroups of order $p^2$ according to Table 1 in [Characteristic Subgroups of Finite Abelian Groups](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927871003591843?needAccess=true), which eliminates this case from my interest.

That leaves $Z_{p^2} \times Z_{p^2} $ and $Z_p \times Z_p \times Z_{p^2} $.

Basically I'm looking for a contradiction with the group that I have where the derived subgroup is abelian with order $p^4$, and the group only has one normal subgroup of order $p^2$.

Comment: In the cyclic case, there will be a unique characteristic subgroup of order $p^2$. Also, $Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^2}$ also has a unique characterstic subgroup of order $p^2$.

Comment: I have eliminated the case with $ Z_p \times Z_p \times Z_{p^2} $, so your comment leaves me only to look at characteristic subgroups of $ Z_{p^2} \times Z_{p^2} $ of order p. If I can find more than one, this case is eliminated.

Comment: You will not find more than one in $Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^2}$, as I said. Moreover, you seem to forgetting about $Z_{p^4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your original comment. I see now that you are saying there is only one characteristic subgroup, and this subgroup has order $p^2$. As for $Z_{p^4}$, this is not possible in my specific situation. Since I have narrowed my cases to just $Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^2}$, you have provided all the information I really needed. Alas, I will have to look elsewhere for my contradiction. Thank you for your help! :)